# Str_replace with regex

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Say I have the following link:

```
<li class="hook">
      <a href="i_have_underscores">I_have_underscores</a>
</li>
```

How would I, remove the underscores **only** in the text and not the href? I have used str_replace, but this removes all underscores, which isn't ideal.

So basically I would be left with this output:

```
<li class="hook">
      <a href="i_have_underscores">I have underscores</a>
</li>
```

Any help, much appreciated

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safer to parse HTML with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of regex. Try this code:

```
<?php

function replaceInAnchors($html)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    // loadHtml() needs mb_convert_encoding() to work well with UTF-8 encoding
    $dom->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    foreach($xpath->query('//text()[(ancestor::a)]') as $node)
    {
        $replaced = str_ireplace('_', ' ', $node->wholeText);
        $newNode  = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
        $newNode->appendXML($replaced);
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
    }

    // get only the body tag with its contents, then trim the body tag itself to get only the original content
    return mb_substr($dom->saveXML($xpath->query('//body')->item(0)), 6, -7, "UTF-8");
}

$html = '<li class="hook">
      <a href="i_have_underscores">I_have_underscores</a>
</li>';
echo replaceInAnchors($html);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get the text within the tags, and then run your `str_replace()` function on the result.

---

Using the DOM Parser I linked, it is as simple as something like this:

```
$html = str_get_html(
    '<li class="hook"><a href="i_have_underscores">I_have_underscores</a></li>');
$links = $html->find('a');   // You can use any css style selectors here

foreach($links as $l) {
    $l->innertext = str_replace('_', ' ', $l->innertext)
}

echo $html
//<li class="hook"><a href="i_have_underscores">I have underscores</a></li>
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks, what part of the site should I look at?

Comment: On the front page you will want to check out the two links under "Download and Documentation"

Comment: It's way slower (30ms vs. 1ms on my machine) than stillstanding's solution, which seems to be the best approach to me (but with `"//text()[(ancestor::a)]"` xPath query).